# Saving data from axios request in a global variable

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm fetching data from an api through axios post request as shown below:

```
useEffect(() => {

Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/getRoomDetails", {
  roomname: roomname,
}).then((response) => {
  details = response.data;
  return details
  
  
}) }, []);
```

Here I declared the `details` variable globally before `useEffect` so that I can display data from it on my react page. But I can't access the `details` variable outside of the promise.
Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `react`, it is customary to store the state of a component in variables that useState provides (if we are talking about functional components). It is a bad idea to declare variables and assign values to them directly. `react` won't be able to track changes to them. Therefore you need to use `useState` hook.

```
const [details, setDetails] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/getRoomDetails", {
    roomname: roomname,
  }).then((response) => {
    setDetails(response.data);
  }) 
}, []);

// and use details variable in jsx
```

While the above code will solve your problem, it is not good practice. I recommend using some kind of state manager for `react` to store the data that was received from **side-effects**. It can be [mobx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mobx) or [redux](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux).